# Special case of perspective projection

Tags: transform, axonometric-projection

I am reading perspective projection from computer Graphics Hearn Baker book. But two concepts are not understanding. [image]

Special cases 3 and 4 not understanding.

**Case:3** when zvp=0 then projection reference point exists in view plane. So how can I get projection? But some website saying the **reference point where all the projectors (projection lines) converge has to have a non-zero coordinate (because you don't get an image if the reference point is in the viewing plane itself).** I don't understanding how?

**Case:4** It maybe understandable after getting knowledge of case 3.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs to computergraphics.se not here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special case 3: zvp=0 only states that the 3d space coordinate system origin happens to be somewhere in the view plane. The reference point can still be elsewhere. If the reference point happened to be in the view plane the image would be a single point, but this is not he case here.

Special case 4: x- and y-coordinates of the reference point happen to be zero in the 3d space coordinate system and the view plane happens to contain the 3d space coordinate system origin. To get something else than a single point image Zrp should be nonzero in this case.